# R cdplot() - does the right axis show probability or density?

Tags: r, probability-density, density-plot

Reproducible data:

```
## NASA space shuttle o-ring failures
fail <- factor(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,
                 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
               levels = 1:2, labels = c("no", "yes"))
temperature <- c(53, 57, 58, 63, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 69, 70, 70,
                 70, 70, 72, 73, 75, 75, 76, 76, 78, 79, 81)

## CD plot
cdplot(fail ~ temperature)
```

The documentation for cdplot says:

> cdplot computes the **conditional densities** of x given the levels of y weighted by the marginal distribution of y. **The densities are derived** cumulatively over the levels of y. **The conditional probabilities are not derived** by discretization (as in the spinogram), but using a smoothing approach via density.The **conditional density functions** (cumulative over the levels of y) **are returned invisibly**.

So on the plot where x = 63, y = 0.4 (approximately). Is this probability, or probability *density*? I am confused by the documentation as to what is calculated, what is returned and what is plotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot shows the *probability* of an outcome for a given temperature.

What the docs are saying is that a standard density distribution is calculated for temperature measurements, and a density is worked out separately for temperature when `fail` is 'no'. If we divide the density of "no" temperatures by the density of all temperatures, then weight this by the proportion of 'no' temperatures, then we will get an estimate of the probability of drawing a "no" at a given temperature.

To show this is the case, let's see the cdplot:

```r
cdplot(fail ~ temperature)
```

[image]

Now let's calculate the probabilities from the marginal densities manually and plot. We should get a near-identical shape to our curve

```r
all <- density(temperature, from = min(temperature), to = max(temperature))

no  <- density(temperature[fail == "no"], from = min(temperature), 
                 to = max(temperature))

probs <- no$y/all$y * proportions(table(fail))[1]

plot(all$x, 1 - probs, type = "l", ylim = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and concise answer, @Allan Cameron, I appreciate it. One question though: the graphs look the same, but the figures (y axis) are different. E.g. calculated from the cdplot if x = 65, the value is 0.2141 but on the second plot the y value at x = 65 is around 0.45, which is quite a big difference. It also means the cdplot() can not show probability on the y axis after all?

Comment: @Reader123 this was really just for illustration, In reality, one would have to weight the density of each group by the count of each. For example, we could get the density of all temperature measurements together with `all <- density(temperature, from = min(temperature), to = max(temperature))` then do `probs <- no$y/all$y * cumsum(proportions(table(fail)))[1]`, and plot with `plot(all$x, 1 - probs)` to get a much closer match to what cdplot does. But in any case, for your data the output of `cdplot` is showing the _estimated_ probability of `temperature` given `fail`

Comment: There are several ways to _estimate_ the probability of `fail` at a particular `temperature` given a set of data, and `cdplot` is just using one method to do this, similar to the method I outline above.

Comment: @Reader123 I have updated to try to mimic more closely what cdplot actually does. It is still not exact, but I would have to rewrite `cdplot` to get it to match exactly.